# Stretching controls to take full screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a video game. I need that it will be available at full screen mode, and with different resolutions.

I already know how to make application maximized and how to remove the built-in user interface, that is not the problem.

The problem is, that when I run it in full mode, all controls simply take the top-left corner, leaving the remaining space empty.

[image: What I have now looks about like this:]

What I want, that controls would be spread evenly across the screen, with new coordinates and sizes, but same proportions.

[image: The expected variant should look like this:]

I tried using anchoring. It works, but only when there is just one control. When there are more controls, and in my menu bar there are 12, and I try using anchoring, they are stretched, but put on top of each other.

Is there a way to get the right result? If so, can you please help me?

Thank you in advance,
Evgenie

Comment: WinForms, sorry for not saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TableLayoutPanel`, anchor it to the left, right and bottom of the form, set `ColumnCount=3`, `RowCount=1`, edit column sizes in the `Columns` property, then drop buttons into corresponding cells and align them using their `Dock`, `Anchor` and `Padding` properties.

Comment: I can check if it helps me only from home, but until then I want to ask something more on that issue. If I understood correctly what columns are, that can help me with the menu bar. But except that bar, there are other controls. For example, there are panels that are used as game rooms. Each panel has buttons, but unlike the menu bar, they are not arranged symmetrically. For example, there is a very large door on the right, medium wardrobe somewhere in the middle and small table on the bottom left. They have different sizes and non symmetrical positions. Can columns be used here too?

Comment: I tried it, and it works. I'll still have to assign some things manually, but creating a TableLayoutPanel is very helpful. The question is answered, my many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is 'Dock' property for controls. You can add controls to a TabaleLayoutPanel and set the Dock property to DockStyle.Fill.

Answer (score 0):

some ways i remember through which you can achieve it

1. **Dock** - [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. **Anchor** - [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. programitically setting the location according to the screen resolution ration

Comment: Unfortunately, both docking and anchoring work only with single control. When there are many, they are put on top of each other, I wrote about it. Unless using tables from previous answer works, I think that manual setting of coordinates and sizes is the only option.